# @foreach loop - linq / razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

i use this code to filter the items in the list.

```
@foreach (var wu in ViewBag.GetWorkUser.Where(op => op.action == 0))
        {@wu.DisplayName}
```

code: linq / Razor

but i getting this error

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation without  first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type

i can´t understand what is wrong here. i have search and try some other code to solved this problem
but still the same error.

someone can give me a hand with this pls?

Comment: you should convert viewbag to your model type

Comment: try to to cast ViewBag.GetWorkUser to List

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ViewBag` is a *dynamic* collection. So the type of `op` (lambda variable) is not known at compile time, you need to cast `ViewBag.GetWorkUser` before using `Where` like this:

```
((IEnumerable<User>)ViewBag.GetWorkUser).Where(op => op.action == 0))
        //    ^^^ User or whatever type you have
```

Comment: great solution and explanation. its working and now i understand what was wrong with my code. thank you very much +1

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach (var wu in ((IEnumerable<User>)ViewBag.GetWorkUser).Where(op => op.action == 0))
{
    wu.DisplayName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correctly way sothing like this:

```
@foreach (var wu in ((List<GetWorkUser>)ViewBag.GetWorkUser).Where(op => op.action == 0)){
    <span> @wu.DisplayName </span>
}
```